# osx editor similar to OmniGraffle

Tags: macos, editor

id like to make an editor similar to OmniGraffle. Basic functionality:
1) add objects
2) live resize objects
3) per object context menu
4) ability to connect objects with a curve so dragging one object would constantly redraw connected curve

Is there any open source libs for that? If not, how do i make my own? Each object should be represented by a layer or it has to be drawn using CG or maybe i'll need display link. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you can refer the Sketch example from Apple Developer Examples.With Mac OS 10.6.x, it is available in the folder /Developer/Examples

This example has basic events handling like drawing on mouse Down etc .

Comment: tnx for a tip. How can i animate object placement on a such field?